# Tkinter: closing windows created using button widgets does not destroy the objects until the applicaiton closes?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Sorry in advance for the long post.

I'm creating a Zip file viewer and editor using TKinter. It's my first time using a GUI in python and it's been a learning curve getting all the concepts in my brain so far. The intention for this project is to connect it to an API that returns zip files with mixed json and csv files within. Becuase I'm still learning about the data in this API, I want to be able to dynamically access the files and explore them without having to write code, run the programme, rely on the console to see the data, write more code, run again etc....I don't have access to jupyter notebooks, conda, or google colab etc.. on the work PC so PyCharm is all I've got at my disposal

The big thing with this gui is that I would like any changes I make to the documents contents to be stored and recallable at any time while the gui is active. Then, when I close the gui, the edited file contents are saved in a specified location outside of the original zip file. For now, there is no save feature in my gui because I have run into a problem.

Here are my packes for reference:

```
import json
import tkinter as tk
from zipfile import ZipFile
from functools import partial
```

My gui has 2 classes: a zip file content explorer class:

```
class ZipViewer(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, zipfile, title="Zip File Explorer"):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.zip = ZipFile(zipfile)
        self.file_list = [i.filename for i in self.zip.filelist]
        self.stored_content = {}
        self.geometry('635x250')
        self.title(title)
        parent = tk.Canvas(self, bg='#0B514F', confine=False)
        parent.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
        rows = self.display_files(parent)
        parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        for r in range(0, rows+1):
            parent.grid_rowconfigure(r, weight=1)

    def __call__(self):
        self.mainloop()
        print("Main window Closed")
        print(f"on window close: {self.stored_content.keys()}")
        return self.stored_content

    def open_file(self, f):
        print(f"target: {f}")
        print(f"on open: {self.stored_content.keys()}")
        try:
            output = TextViewer(self.stored_content[f])
        except KeyError as e:
            print(f"File Now Opening: {e}")
            output = json.load(self.zip.open(f))
            output = json.dumps(output, indent=4)
            output = TextViewer(output)
        self.stored_content[f] = output()
        print(f"on object close: {self.stored_content.keys()}")

    def display_files(self, parent):
        col_num = 1
        row_num = -1
        for file in self.file_list:
            if file.split(".")[-1] in _filetype_list:
                p = partial(self.open_file, file)
                button = tk.Button(parent, text=file, command=p,)
                button.grid(
                    column=0 if col_num == 1 else 1,
                    row=row_num+1 if col_num == 1 else row_num
                )
                if col_num == 1:
                    col_num = 0
                    row_num += 1
                else:
                    col_num = 1
        return row_num
```

and a text viewer class:

```
class TextViewer(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, text, title='Text Viewer'):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.data = text
        self.geometry('1000x500')
        self.title(title)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="black")
        self.content = tk.Text(canvas,)
        scrolly = tk.Scrollbar(self.content, 
              orient='vertical', command=self.content.yview)
        self.content.config(yscrollcommand=scrolly.set)
        canvas.pack(fill="both", anchor="nw", expand=True)
        for line in self.data:
            self.content.insert(tk.END, line)
        self.content.pack(side="left", anchor="nw", fill="both", expand=True)
        scrolly.pack(side="right", anchor="e", fill="y")
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)

    def __call__(self):
        self.mainloop()
        return self.data

    def __del__(self):
        print("Object Destroyed")

    def on_closing(self):
        self.data = self.content.get(tk.CURRENT, tk.END)
        self.destroy()
        self.__del__()
```

and a short piece of code to make it run:

```
root = 'FILE_PATH_HERE'
gui = ZipViewer(f"{root}\\testfile.zip")
content = gui()

print(content)
```

Full disclosure: I also have a DataFrameViewer class - but for the sake of this question, it's not built any different from the TextViewer class and, conceptually, I think we only need to focus on the problem once and the answer should be applicable to all other classes that end up in the interface.

As you can see, in my classes I've set some messages to print when certain events are triggered. This is how I noticed some unexpected behaviour which I think is the cause of my problem.

The problem is when I click a button to open a file then close that Textviewer window, the ZipFileViewer.stored_content attribute does not get updated. The attribute only gets updated when I close the main ZipFileViewer window. This means that any changes I make to the documents are ot being stored and recalled as I would like. I also noticed that, even though the TextFileViewer objects are deleted once I close the windows, the objects don't seem to actually get destroyed because, when I close the ZipFileViewer window, I get console messages to say that the other objects have been destroyed again. Since that particular message only comes from the textFileViewer class, I can only assume that the objects are hanging around in the system when they shouldn't be.

Below is a version of the console output I was expecting to see when I ran my programme (I've added notes here to show when I perform certain actions in my gui):

```
application start, ZipViewer (gui) called
json file opened in TextViewer
>>> target: AZ5011001156477.JSON
>>> on open: dict_keys([])
>>> File Now Opening: 'AZ5011001156477.JSON'

Changes made
textViewer closed
>>> Object Destroyed
>>> on object close: dict_keys(['AZ5011001156477.JSON'])

json file reopened through gui window
(note: edited doc contents to be recalled from self.stored_content)
>>> target: AZ5011001156477.JSON
>>> on open: dict_keys(['AZ5011001156477.JSON'])

Further Changes made
TextViewer Closed
>>> Object Destroyed
>>> on object close: dict_keys(['AZ5011001156477.JSON'])

Main gui window closed 
>>> Main window Closed
>>> on window close: dict_keys(['AZ5011001156477.JSON'])
>>> {'AZ5011001156477.JSON': "SECONDARY EDITED FILE CONTENTS HERE"
>>> 
>>> Process finished with exit code 0
```

But the actual console gives me this (with action notes):

```
application start, ZipViewer (gui) called
json file opened in TextViewer
>>> target: AZ5011001156477.JSON
>>> on open: dict_keys([])
>>> File Now Opening: 'AZ5011001156477.JSON'

Changes made
textViewer closed
>>> Object Destroyed

json file reopened through gui window
(note: Previously made changes are currently not being recalled here)
>>> target: AZ5011001156477.JSON
>>> on open: dict_keys([])
>>> File Now Opening: 'AZ5011001156477.JSON'

closed without Changes
>>> Object Destroyed

Main gui window closed 
>>> on object close: dict_keys(['AZ5011001156477.JSON'])
>>> on object close: dict_keys(['AZ5011001156477.JSON'])
>>> Main window Closed
>>> on window close: dict_keys(['AZ5011001156477.JSON'])
>>> {'AZ5011001156477.JSON': "PRIMARY EDITED FILE CONTENTS HERE"
>>> Object Destroyed
>>> Object Destroyed
>>> 
>>> Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm not entirely sure why there is this difference in behaviour but at the moment I'm making the following assumptions:

1. Creating a window off of an existing window somehow ties the 2 together, and the secondary window doesn't truly get destroyed until the primary window closes
2. Maybe the button actions don't behave like I think they do? I would expect them to be a one-time click - action - end type behaviour, but perhaps the action somehow lingers until the application closes?

I've been on this for a couple of days now and the official docs are starting to become a huge blur to me. Can you explain why I'm seeing this behaviour and suggest a way to correct it to what I want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'd forgotten about 2 important tkinter ideas:

1. you shouldn't create simultaneous windows using tk.Tk() - instead, use tk.Toplevel() when creating your second window
2. self.destroy() closes the window, but **del** is for the garbage collector. self.quit() is the method I needed to actually destroy the object.

So I rewrote my TextViewer class to look like this:

```
class _TextViewer(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root, text, title='Text Viewer'):
        self.data = text
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, root)
        self.geometry('1000x500')
        self.title(title)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="black")
        self.content = tk.Text(
            canvas,
            bg='black',
            fg="white",
            font=("arial", 16)
        )
        scrolly = tk.Scrollbar(self.content, 
                        orient='vertical', command=self.content.yview)
        self.content.config(yscrollcommand=scrolly.set)
        canvas.pack(fill="both", anchor="nw", expand=True)
        for line in self.data:
            self.content.insert(tk.END, line)
        self.content.pack(side="left", anchor="nw", 
                        fill="both", expand=True)
        scrolly.pack(side="right", anchor="e", fill="y")
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)

    def __del__(self):
        print("Object Destroyed")

    def grab_set(self):
        self.mainloop()
        return self.data

    def on_closing(self):
        self.data = self.content.get(tk.CURRENT, tk.END)
        self.destroy()
        self.quit()
```

Note: In the ZipFileViewer class I also replaced the output() call with output.grab_set()
And my console output on my next run looked like this:

```
Start the application
open the json file
>>> target: AZ5011001156477.JSON
>>> on open: dict_keys([])
>>> File Now Opening: 'AZ5011001156477.JSON'

make edits
close the window
>>> on object close: dict_keys(['AZ5011001156477.JSON'])

reopen the json file
(note: previous edits are now visible)
>>> target: AZ5011001156477.JSON
>>> on open: dict_keys(['AZ5011001156477.JSON'])

make more edits
close the window
>>> on object close: dict_keys(['AZ5011001156477.JSON'])

close the main  gui window
>>> Main window Closed
>>> on window close: dict_keys(['AZ5011001156477.JSON'])
>>> {'AZ5011001156477.JSON': "SECONDARY CHANGES HERE"
>>> Object Destroyed
>>> Object Destroyed
>>> 
>>> Process finished with exit code 0
```

So problem solved!